# SQL Query always returning 1 regardless of result

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am creating a function in PHP to count the number of same emails in my SQL table, however the function is returning 1 regardless of result. Here is my PHP code:

```
$query = Query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` AS total WHERE `email` = '$email");
return $query->fetch();
```

I have run the function in phpmyadmin and it returns the correct count but, in PHP it fails.
Note:
I have another function which is nearly same and it is working perfactly:

```
$query = Query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total
    FROM `passwords` WHERE `password` = '$pwd'");
return $query->fetch();
```

Comment: If you're getting results from the second query, it means you're not hashing passwords like you should.

Comment: Are you sure `$email` is set correctly?

Comment: $email is set correctly, Here is the full code

Comment: function GetEmailCount($conn, $email)
{
    $query = Query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) as total
    FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
    return $query->fetch();
}

Comment: How does that show that `$email` is set to the email that has duplicates?

Comment: Since I called the function myself. The email has no duplicates, but it is returning 1. I tried with duplicates and it still returns 1

Comment: 1 means it has no duplicates, it's the only one.

Comment: Is it supposed to be an email that isn't in the table, so you expect 0?

Comment: But the $email is not inserted in the table. It should returns 0 since there is no duplicate. Also it returns 1 still when I added duplicates

Comment: Are you looking at `$row['total']`?

Comment: I tried $row['total'] and it throws an error. Then I tried $query->fetch() and it returns the result

Comment: What variable do you assign the function result to?

Comment: directly echo them

Comment: `Query()` is not a standard PHP MySQL function, I don't know what it returns.

Comment: It looks like you're using your own DB class, what does `fetch()` return?

Comment: It is a function I defined. It prepares the query through mysqliObject->prepare() and then executes and returns the executed query

Comment: fetch() is the mysqli defined function, I am not using my own db class. However I am going to create one as soon as my functions starts to work

Comment: You should be using `fetch_assoc()` or `fetch_array()`. `fetch()` doesn't return the results, it just returns true or false.

Comment: It's used along with `bind_result()`, which lets you specify variables to hold the returned columns.

Comment: Well, I hadn't thought of this. It means password function is returning false which is being converted to 0?

Comment: You also need to use `$stmt->get_results()`.

Comment: It returns true when there's a row returned, false when there are no more rows. `SELECT COUNT(*)` should always return 1 row, so you shouldn't get `0`.

Comment: I managed to fix it, thanks to your help. If you post it in answers then I will upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fetch_assoc()`, not `fetch()`, and extract the `total` column from the result.

```
$query = Query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` AS total WHERE `email` = '$email");
return $query->fetch_assoc()['total'];
```